# disable editing in QSpinbox but enable arrows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, readonly, qspinbox

I have a QSpinBox in which I want to enable the arrows (for up and down values) but disable inserting data by the user.
I've tried using this:

```
QtGui.QSpinBox.setReadOnly(True)
```

But it doesn't work. All is disabled and the arrows are 'stuck'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you set the spin-box readonly, it will disable *eveything*. Instead, just set the line-edit readonly, and then buttons will still work:

```
spinbox.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can block spinboxes editor by `QtGui.QSpinBox.lineEdit().setEnabled(False)`.

**edit:** and set font color and background-color:

```
spinbox.lineEdit().setStyleSheet('color: black; background-color: white;')
```

Comment: Thx, it works. Any idea how do I change the font color? It greys out the spinbox background and the font. I tried this: QtGui.QSpinBox.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(161,161,161); ")  but still the font is grey

Comment: i think, the solution of @ekhumoro has some advantages: 'setStyleSheet' is not necessary, the user can copy the value to clipboard and no cursor is shown when 'readOnly' is set to True

Comment: The color black and background color-white does not seem to work... any idea?

Answer (score 3):

In case someone looking for an answer for this problem in C++ come here (like me), the other answers are not straightforward because QSpinBox::lineEdit() is a protected member (so it would require to also extend the class).

What worked for me was:

```cpp
    auto l1SpinBox = new QSpinBox(this);
    auto lineEdit = l1SpinBox->findChild<QLineEdit*>();
    lineEdit->setReadOnly(true);
    lineEdit->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    connect(l1SpinBox, static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged), l1SpinBox,
            [&, lineEdit](){lineEdit->deselect();}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

setReadOnly alone may do the trick for you. However in my case, I wanted to improve UI making it also not focusable, and then hiding the selection when the value changes.